# SP 2010 Windows Authentication Default Login

Tags: 2010, development, web-services, anonymous-authentication, windows-authentication

I want to be able to use a simple HttpModule to catch visits to a sharepoint site that don't automaticly pass windows authentication and log them in as a default windows account.

I want it to be so that any browser that accesses the sharepoint site that doesn't right away pass windows auth it will goto this other windows account.

What I don't know how to do is the following:

- Detect that the browser did not send windows authentication for the connection.

  - Get an event handler on that and send it to a login function
  - Then the authentication cycle would have to be redone
- Login the user into sharepoint as a windows account with username and password

  - For this part I'm guessing code on this page might work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx.  Except I of course don't want to prompt the user for a username/password I want to use one I already have in a settings file or something like that.

The scenario for this is because I haven't found the anonymous access in sharepoint to be the most supportive.  I do alot of javascript stuff, and I ran into a road block trying to access the listdata.svc service when a user was anonymous.  It seems like there has to be a simpler, possibly totaly unsupported way of doing things.  A way that gives you total control over exactly what the default user can and cannot do.

Comment: The problem you are going to have is that the first time a browser connects it will access the site without passing any credentials. IIS will return 401 asking the browser to authenticate.